# Working of Midi files in android

Tags: android, midi, opensl

I am trying to understand the working of playing midi files in Android.I know that Android uses Sonivox Eas Libraries and OpenSL ES libraries.But I wanted to get into more details and wanted to know how these libraries are called and what are the functions of these libraries.
Also I wanted to generate my own MIDI notes that could be streamed or read and the output sound could be produced.How can i do that?
I am thinking of making an Android application for playing a MIDI file . How can i start with building the application? What other libraries apart from mentioned above would be needed to play a midi file.
I am planning to use native (C++/C) android development to make this android application.